# Poem: "The Folded and the Quiet" by Henry E. Sostman

Tags: poetry, james-blish

In [*Cities in Flight*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?27777) (1970, p. 542), James Blish quoted two lines from a long, unpublished poem by Henry E. Sostman called "The Folded and the Quiet":

> I grow not out of salt nor out of soil
>
> But out of that which pains me

Sostman is not listed in the ISFDB. A little sleuthing on Google shows that he was a temperature physicist who lived from 1920 to 1999. Blish was of about the same age (1921–1975) and often wrote science fiction that included discussions of physics. Sostman wrote technical papers on [gallium](https://academic.oup.com/clinchem/article-abstract/23/4/725/5673422), a metal whose unusually low melting point and reactivity Blish worked into a dramatic event in his 1967 novel, [*A Torrent of Faces*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11873). Evidently the two knew each other around 1967–1970.

Has any more of Sostman's poem been published?

Comment: It looks like Blish quoted the poem again in *Anywhen*, but different lines, "We learn from words, but never learn much more / than that from time to time the same things happen."

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v34n11_1960-11_UnkSc-cape1736/#page/n127/mode/2up has a better source for that quote than what I was drawing on, and it looks like it's just one sentence and it's not outright stated to be part of the poem. Also, it's from "And Some Were Savages". *Anywhen* was a story collection.

Comment: On at least one occasion he went by Henry Ernst Sostmann (with a double-n); https://www.ncsli.org/pubs/Newsletters/1996-10-NLa.pdf. He may also have had a nickname ("Bud")

Comment: His obit is here; http://obits.abqjournal.com/obits/search?page=9997&query=albuquerque. Wife died three years later; http://obits.abqjournal.com/obits/search?page=8096&query=albuquerque - Theodora G. Sostmann. Survived by her son, Henry (Dirk) Sostman (single n), MD, FACR - https://www.houstonmethodist.org/faculty/henrydirk-sostman/. I shall drop him a tweet.

Comment: This search is not being helped by the fact that he had no less than 7 forms of his name that he evidently used; "Henry Sostman", "Henry Sostmann", "Henry E Sostman", "Henry Ernst Sostman", "Henry Ernst Sostmann", "Bud Sostman" and "Bud Sostmann". Why can't people have a single, easily-googled name?

Comment: @Valorum Any word back from Sostman Jr.? If not, I shall have to ask FuzzyBoots to convert the comment to an answer, given the way that I worded the question.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron - Nothing yet.

Comment: Thanks for trying, Valorum. I really would like to read the poem. Well, FuzzyBoots, the ball's in your court now; thank you for locating another fragment!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots? Would you like to recast your comment as an answer?

Comment: I have added what I have found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one more potential fragment that I have found. In "[And Some Were Savages](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57691)" (available online in [*Amazing Stories* v. 34, Nov. 1960](https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v34n11_1960-11_UnkSc-cape1736/#page/n127/mode/2up)), a line is alluded to as being part of Sostman's poem.

> So I thought; but like most
> people, I underestimated the viability of the past, the one thing
> the poets have been trying to
> pound into our corporate pinheads since words were invented :
>
> > *We learn from words, but
> > never learn much more than
> > that from time to time the
> > same things happen.*
>
> But I wasn’t then thinking
> about *The Folded and the Quiet*;
> the quotation didn’t become attached to the Savannah affair in
> my mind until long afterward,
> when I encountered the poem
> during one of my dead-space
> reading jags. Now, I didn’t really
> know what was the matter, and
> so all I could do was to continue
> to set up the tab board.